# Recover length of Drawable[]

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to know if it is possible to recover the length of a drawable[].

I've tried to do that like I did for a Integer[] :

```
int count;
count = myDrawable[].length;
```

but it takes like 5s to return the result (the drawable[] contain only 4 rows).

```
Drawable[] theme = {    
    Drawable.createFromStream(expansionFile.getInputStream("amiante_plombier_ce_1.png"), "src"),
    Drawable.createFromStream(expansionFile.getInputStream("amiante_plombier_ce_2.png"), "src"),
    Drawable.createFromStream(expansionFile.getInputStream("amiante_plombier_ce_3.png"), "src"),
    Drawable.createFromStream(expansionFile.getInputStream("amiante_plombier_ce_4.png"), "src"),
};
```

Any idea why it takes so long ?

Comment: Decoding an image from a file is no easy task - how large are the images you are decoding?

Comment: I think I expressed myself poorly, I want to know how many rows are in my drawable [], for this example, it should return me "4".

Comment: I understand that - but you are expecting these pngs to decode instantaneously, which will never be possible with any hardware. I think you should re-think your design approach in this scenario.

Comment: No no, I can decode the pngs, it's not the problem; if I define count=4, the app works perfectly (it still take some time to load, but it's not a big deal), but I cannot get dynamically the size of my Drawable[] .

Comment: Is `myDrawable[].length` the way it actually is in your code, or is that a typo? It should be `myDrawable.length`(no brackets). Or, more appropriate to the example you gave, `theme.length`

Comment: I call theme.length. But when I do that, it seems that it is looping many time before returning a result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, the point is that I was using my `int count; count = myDrawable[].length;` inside the function getCount() of a PagerAdapter, I had to initialise `count` outside of the function, and make a test for `count` in order to avoid looping and checking many time inside my expansionFile. It works perfectly with something like this :

```
    public int count = -1;

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        if (count == -1){
            try {
                count = theme.length;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```